# How to add ZK theme into iDempiere?

Tags: zk, idempiere

I'm researching how to using iDempiere fw. I tried using ZK theme into iDempiere fw by link [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/Theming_and_Styling/ZK_Official_Themes/ZK_Bootstrap_Theme).

First time, I put the *zk-bootstrap.jar* file under *WEB-INF/lib* folder in *org.adempiere.ui.zk* project.

In *zk.xml* file, I insert lines of code:

```
<library-property>
    <name>org.zkoss.zul.Button.mold</name>
    <value>bs</value>
</library-property>
<library-property>
    <name>org.zkoss.zul.Menupopup.mold</name>
    <value>bs</value>
</library-property>
<library-property>
    <name>org.zkoss.zkmax.zul.Navbar.mold</name>
    <value>bs</value>
</library-property>
<library-property>
    <name>org.zkoss.zul.Paging.mold</name>
    <value>bs</value>
</library-property>
<library-property>
    <name>org.zkoss.zul.Panel.mold</name>
    <value>bs</value>
</library-property>
```

And I run iDempiere fw again. But it doesn't work. It only display this screen:

[image: iDempiere screen].

Please help!

Comment: Because I'm a beginner. Please present for details

Comment: Zk version? Plus, if you open your browser console it has to be some errors

Comment: @AlexGreg Latest version. I runs it again but can't get anything error.

Comment: go to your browser, press `Ctrl+Shift+c`, go to `Console` tab and then reload the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a published way to add ZK Theme as another plugin into the project. You can refer to its online documentation here http://wiki.idempiere.org/en/Add_your_theme